# Error Cannot read properties of undefined 'Symbol(immer-state)'

Tags: heroku, redux

Build simple project with ROR and React/Redux RTK. Locally works fine. Also with `heroku local`. But once I upload to Heroku, when I'm modyfing state with Redux I see error. Completely don't know what to do with it.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(immer-state)')
```

From stack I see that it happens somewhere around EntityAdapter function call .addOne and .removeOne. While /setAll, and .upsertOne works fine...

Reducer:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
builder
  .addCase(fetchTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.status = "succeeded";
    todosAdapter.setAll(state, action);
  })
  .addCase(fetchTodos.pending, (state, action) => {
    state.status = "loading";
  })
  .addCase(createTodo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    todosAdapter.addOne(state, action);
  })
  .addCase(updateTodo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    todosAdapter.upsertOne(state, action);
  })
  .addCase(deleteTodo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    todosAdapter.removeOne(state, action.payload.id);
  });
```

},

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by turning off uglification via Rails:

```
production.rb
# config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```